# Undefined index: user.passwordResetTokenExpire Yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm working on Yii2 method to reset the password and so far sends the email with the link to the password change but pressing on this error link.

Undefined index: user.passwordResetTokenExpire

This is the model code which marks the error:

```
public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)
{
    if (empty($token)) {
        return false;
    }

    $timestamp = (int) substr($token, strrpos($token, '_') + 1);
    $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
    return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
}
```

I'm using the code suggested by the framework but apparently not this or that function is not me if something is missing in the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved one must add the following line in the config file params.php

```
'user.passwordResetTokenExpire' => 3600,
```

Thanks